# Country code changes to its initial value after saving phone number

Tags: flutter

I am using [intl_phone_number_input](https://pub.dev/packages/intl_phone_number_input)  in Flutter to save the user's contact number. When I choose a country code for saving user's phone number, let's say I select OMAN `OM` country, and save the number, then when I come again on this screen, the country code changes to its initial value which is UAE `AE`. I just want to solve this problem how to persist the country code?

Here is my code:

```
class SocialLinks extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(Map<String, String>) callBack;

  const SocialLinks(this.callBack, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SocialLinks> createState() => _SocialLinksState();
}

class _SocialLinksState extends State<SocialLinks> {
  var whatsappController = TextEditingController();
  var phoneNumber = PhoneNumber(isoCode: 'AE');

  Map<String, String> data = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
     
      whatsappController.text = Get.put(AppController()).loginResponse?.data?.user?.whatsApp ?? "";
      setState(() {});
      final savedPhoneNumber = Get.put(AppController()).loginResponse?.data?.user?.whatsApp;
      if (savedPhoneNumber != null && savedPhoneNumber.isNotEmpty) {
        phoneNumber = PhoneNumber(isoCode: 'AE', phoneNumber: savedPhoneNumber);
      }
    });
    
    data["whatsApp"] = whatsappController.text.trim();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
                children: [
                 InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
                    initialValue: phoneNumber,
                    textFieldController: whatsappController,
                    onInputChanged: (PhoneNumber number) {
                      phoneNumber = number;
                    },
                    selectorConfig: const SelectorConfig(
                      selectorType: PhoneInputSelectorType.BOTTOM_SHEET,
                    ),
                    countries: const ['AE', 'BH', 'SA', 'KW', 'OM', 'QA', 'EG'],
                    keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true, decimal: true),
                    inputBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                    onSaved: (PhoneNumber number) {
                  phoneNumber = number;
                },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height15),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
if (phoneNumber.phoneNumber != null && phoneNumber.phoneNumber!.isNotEmpty) {
                        data["whatsApp"] = phoneNumber.phoneNumber!;
                      }
                      Provider.of<UserProfileService>(context, listen: false).updateUserProfile(context, data, {});
                      Get.back();
                    },
                    child: SmallText(text: LanguageStringKeys.instance.save.tr, color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you remove unnecessary parts of that arent needed to reproduce the issue and widgets like `AppTextField` are unknown

Comment: I have removed unnecessary parts.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Bro I am waiting for your kind reply

Comment: I can give a try without getx,

Comment: sure, I'll wait.

Comment: You are setting here `if (savedPhoneNumber != null && savedPhoneNumber.isNotEmpty) {
        phoneNumber = PhoneNumber(isoCode: 'AE', phoneNumber: savedPhoneNumber);
      }` `AE` as hard-coded

Comment: Yes, here i have initialized `var phoneNumber = PhoneNumber(isoCode: 'AE');`

Comment: `persist the country code` on route you can use the statement solution ,

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreferences` package to store the country code , and when the page is opened call it , is easy to use .

Comment: so is this the only way ? Isn't there any way ?

Comment: You can use any package that stores data on phone storage , but the easiest is SharedPreferences .